# The no. of ways dividing a polygon with $n+1$ sides into triangular regions....

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

Please if any one can help me explaining this concept, I can't proceed further due to this....

> Let $h(n)$ denote the no. of ways dividing a convex polygon region with $(n+1)$ sides into triangular regions by inserting diagonals which does not intersect in interior.
>   We assume:
>     $h(1)=1$ ,then the formula is:
>                      $$h(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}h(k)h(n-k)$$
>
> **Proof** :
>                         $$\text{for}~~n=1,h(1)=1,$$ 
>                                $$n=2,h(2)=1$$
>                          $\text{for}~~n\geq3,$ consider $a(n+1)$ polygon say $[A_1 ~~A_2~~ A_3 \ldots A_{n+1}]$
>
> for any given $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n-1$ ,We choose $C$ such that if we move clockwise along vertices of polygon we have :=
>    $A=A_1,A_2,A_3\ldots,C=A_{k+1},A_{k+2}\ldots ,A_{n+1}=B$
>
> ways of dividing $R_1$ into triangles - $h(k)$ and
>   ways of dividing $R_2$ into triangles $h(n-k)$
>
> $\therefore $ no. of ways = $h(k)h(n-k)$ 
>    for any given k with $1\leq k\leq n-1$ ,we choose $C$ such that :
>                 $$A=A_1,C=A_{k+1},B=A_{n+1}$$
>
> The triangle $T=[A,B,C]$ divides polygonal region into $3$ parts .
>     $R_1,T$ and $R_2$ with :
>      $R_1$  $(k+1)$ polygon
>      $R_2$  $(n+k-1)$ polygon.
>
> The no. of ways of dividing $R_1$ into $\triangle$'s=$h(k)$
>    The no. of ways of dividing $R_2$ into $\triangle$'s=$h(n+k)$.
>
> The no. of triangularization of polygon such that :=
>              $T=[A_1,A_{k+1},A_{n+1}]$  , $1\leq k\leq n-1$
>
> is one of $\triangle=h(k)h(n-k)$
>
> $\therefore$ total no. of ways= $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}h(k)h(n-k)$

Can someone explain the steps in the proof to me as I can't get how did we get the no. of ways of triangularization  .........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Draw a picture*. If you think about the polygon having vertices $A_1$, $A_2, \dotsc, A_{n+1}$, you can subdivide into two smaller polygons by drawing a line from $A_1$ to $A_{k+1}$ for $k=2, \dotsc, n-1$. One of those polygons has $k+1<n+1$ vertices, so it has $h(k)$ triangulations by induction. The other has $n-k+1<n+1$ vertices, so it has $h(n-k)$ triangulations by induction. So the total ways of triangulating the original polygon, starting with a line from $A_1$ to $A_{k+1}$, is $h(k)h(n-k)$. There is one other possibility; namely that $A_1A_2A_{n+1}$ is one of the triangles. In this case, the remaining polygon has $n$ vertices, so we get $h(1)h(n-1)$ triangulations in this case. Since all triangulations fall into one of these cases, the total number of triangulations is
$$h(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} h(k)h(n-k),$$
which is what you want. (Incidentally, this series of numbers is called the *Catalan numbers*.)

Comment: I started getting things a little bit..but what I can't understand is what is procedure of creating triangle $T=[A~~B~~C]$ ..and finally how we write no. of ways of triangularization of polygon s.t.:= $T=[A_1,A_{k+1},A_{n+1}]$.. ..  can you please help me with this...

Comment: Hold on, editing...what I wrote was not quite right.

Comment: I hope that what I wrote answers the question you asked in the comment above: triangularizations of $[A_1,A_{k+1},A_{n+1}]$ are created by any triangularization of the polygon whose vertices are $A_1, A_2, \dotsc, A_{k+1}$ and any triangularization of the polygon whose vertices are $A_1, A_{k+1}, A_{k+2}, \dotsc, A_{n+1}$.

Comment: How come that when proceeding like this, we never end up with the same triangles?